# File Picker drag and drop of folder shows error message

Tags: filepicker.io, filepicker

We are using filepicker for uploading the file and drag and drop of the folders.

and we set the mimetype only for the pdfs as we need only pdf files, and so if we drag and drop the folder, there is a red color error message that only pdfs can be uploaded.

So what should we do, so that we dont see that error message while drag and droping a folder, Is it something we need to set any mimetype even to upload a folder?

Answer (score 1):

For this options it works fine:

```
filepicker.pickMultiple(
    {
        mimetype:'application/pdf',
        services: ['COMPUTER'],
        folders:true
    },
    function(Blobs){  
        Blobs.forEach(addLink);         
    }
);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/krystiangw/vusa6yLm/)

Try to drop folder with pdf files (works for Chrome browser).